# Python: Sharing a time Lock in between spawned Processes so that there is a delay between them

Tags: python, multiprocessing, locking

I am trying to print the id's in this list with them having a delay in between the start and end of the process, and having a delay between the queue.get(which I implement using a threading.Timer with a shared lock). The problem I am having is that while my current setup of having a Timer allows me to lock the processes so that there is a 2 second period after one process acquires the record from the queue that all other processes cannot start, my program only closes 2 of the 4 processes at the end of the program run. How can I fix this so that all the processes close and the program can exit.

My output below shows this as I want there to be 2 more "worker closed" notifications:

```
Process started
Process started
Process started
Process started
begin 1 : 1560891818.0307562
begin 2 : 1560891820.0343137
begin 3 : 1560891822.0381632
end 2 : 3.0021514892578125
end 1 : 6.004615068435669
begin 4 : 1560891824.0439706
begin 5 : 1560891826.0481522
end 4 : 3.004107713699341
end 3 : 6.005637168884277
begin 6 : 1560891828.0511773
begin 7 : 1560891830.0557532
end 6 : 3.0032966136932373
end 5 : 6.006829261779785
begin 8 : 1560891832.056265
begin 9 : 1560891834.0593572
end 8 : 3.011284112930298
end 7 : 6.005618333816528
begin 10 : 1560891836.0627353
end 10 : 3.0014095306396484
worker closed
end 9 : 6.000675916671753
worker closed
```

```py
import multiprocessing
from time import sleep, time
import threading

class TEMP:

    lock = multiprocessing.Lock()

    id_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

    queue = multiprocessing.Queue(10)

    DELAY = 2

    def mp_worker(self, queue, lock):

        while queue.qsize() > 0:

            lock.acquire()
            # Release the lock after a delay
            threading.Timer(self.DELAY,lock.release).start()

            record = queue.get()
            start_time = time()
            print("begin {0} : {1}".format(record, start_time))
            if (record % 2 == 0):
                sleep(3)
            else:
                sleep(6)
            print("end {0} : {1}".format(record, time() - start_time))

            threading.Timer.join()

        print("worker closed")

    def mp_handler(self):

        # Spawn two processes, assigning the method to be executed
        # and the input arguments (the queue)
        processes = [multiprocessing.Process(target=self.mp_worker, args=([self.queue, self.lock])) \
            for _ in range(4)]

        for process in processes:
            process.start()
            print('Process started')


        for process in processes:
            process.join()

    def start_mp(self):

        for id in self.id_list:
            self.queue.put(id)

        self.mp_handler()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    temp = TEMP()
    temp.start_mp()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually fixed this problem. The main reason my code was not joining was because my code was checking if the queue was empty, waiting for a delay, then attempting to get something from the queue. This meant that towards the end of the program that while the queue had become empty and 2 of the 4 processes successfully finished at the same time, the remaining 2 processes were in a delay. When this delay ended they attempted to get something from the queue but since the queue was empty they just blocked the remainder of the process's code from running which meant that they could never join back up.

I fixed this by also checking if the queue is empty right before the process attempts to get something from the queue. My fixed workerfunction is below:

```
def mp_worker(self, queue, lock):

    while not queue.empty():

        print(mp.current_process().name)
        lock.acquire()
        # Release the lock after a delay
        timer = Timer(self.DELAY, lock.release)
        timer.start()

        if not queue.empty():
            record = queue.get(False)

            start_time = time()
            print("begin {0} : {1}".format(record, start_time))
            if (record % 2 == 0):
                sleep(3)
            else:
                sleep(6)
            print("end {0} : {1}".format(record, time() - start_time))

    print("{0} closed".format(mp.current_process().name))
```